# Ldap authentication behaving differently if accessed from some other domain

Tags: php, zend-framework, active-directory, ldap

I am using [Zend Ldap](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-ldap/) to build an authentication system for PHP application. The users are stored in an Active Directory.

Here is some config for ldap:

```
'host'                   => 'ad-host',
'port'                   => '389',
'useStartTls'            => false,
'accountDomainName'      => 'SOMEDOMAIN.local',
'accountDomainNameShort' => 'SOMEDOMAIN',
'baseDn'                 => 'DC=somedomain,DC=local',
'accountCanonicalForm'   => 3
```

Now when I bind through a username(say: testuser) and a password, the username is actually used as: `SOMEDOMAIN\testuser`
and I am successfully able to get authenticated but when I change the `accountDomainNameShort to SOMEDOMAIN.local` then I get an error for `Invalid Credentials`. Now there's a friend of mine who is in a different domain from me but has access to `ad-host`. This user is able to authenticate through ldap when the `accountDomainNameShort is SOMEDOMAIN.local` but when he uses `accountDomainNameShort as just SOMEDOMAIN` he is not able to connect to the LDAP server and gets an Exception of `Ldap server Down`. This exception was acceptable to me thinking he needed the fully qualified name.

But the problem is: When I login to my Windows machine through the same user (testuser), I am able to login using both: `SOMEDOMAIN.local\testuser` and `SOMEDOMAIN\testuser` but when I login through Ldap, I am not able to do so with `SOMEDOMAIN.local\testuser`. Its really bugging me as why its behaving differently? Does window's AD's authentication differ from the Ldap's authetication? If so, why is ldap authetication letting my friend IN when he uses `SOMEDOMAIN.local`. What should my `accountDomainNameShort` be??

Comment: SOMEDOMAIN.local\testuser will fail but testuser@SOMEDOMAIN.local will work fine. 

(not tested with Zend Framework but it works with native PHP LDAP_bind())

Comment: Yeah, I have tested that, when I don't provide the `AccountDomainNameShort` and `accountCanonicalForm` configs, I am able to login with something like: `testuser@SOMEDOMAIN.local` as you mentioned. But don't understand why is `SOMEDOMAIN.local\testuser` failing for me and valid for my friend?

Comment: If you supply the `username` as just "testuser" (no domain), does it work in both cases?

Comment: Windows probably does some magic if you type in "SOMEDOMAIN.local\testuser". It's likely not AD itself.

Comment: The other user is in a different domain, so he will be unreachable, without the DOMAIN name. Thanks for that `magic` comment :). We have agreed to not use the `accountDomainNameShort` but rather use it like: testuser@somedomain.local. This works for both of us.